# How do you choose color such that it is as consistent as possible across devices?

Tags: color, color-reproduction

I have an application and website that uses a certain orange color as the main background. Because I look at it all day, I am always surprised and sometimes put off by how it looks on other devices. (My intention is that it has a more earthy/natural feel, but it is almost bright/fluorescent on some devices).

I understand that it is not possible to control every device and screen in the world, so my question is, how do we compromise to ensure something that is reasonably consistent across devices. I feel like I need to adjust the color to be even more "earthy" than I am comfortable with to compensate for the fact the color is "hotter" on other devices.

What guideline, rule, or practice should designers be using to minimize the problem with achieving an intended color across a wide range of devices?

Comment: You should not really adjust your screen. What you should do is reset screen colors, then run hardware profiler on your screen too make a profile for it and then you can set your hardware to emulate sRGB (either run your monitor in sRGB or turn your application to emulete sRGB). This way your monitor is showing what its supposed to look like. If you dont do this your work is random and worthless, but in general you have no control over this.

Comment: Adjusting my screen doesn't solve the problem of finding a compromise color that looks like I am expecting across a wide variety of devices.  Unless, what you mean is, I should adjust my screen to that compromise position so that while I am designing, I am lead to choose colors that are a little more consistent across devices?

Comment: The closest you can get to any kind of universal colour control is to calibrate your screen  (usually requires a hardware colour calibration device), and then save your images with an embedded sRGB colour profile. But how these would actually display on any given device will be down to the hardware and user settings. There's no way to control these unless these devices are also colour calibrated - but that is something the user of each device would have to do.

Comment: no i mean adjust your monitor to defaults. Run a profiler (or as billy kerr calls it a calibrator) which is essentially a colorimeter. Then your monitor can be as close as possible to sRGB or emulate sRGB. Then adjust the lighting of the space to be neutral gray. That is the best you can hope to do.

Comment: I agree with the other comments, and my advice would be to simply live with it. But of course some designs are more risky than others. A pure black and white design (or even primary colors) would probably be understood by any user on any trash monitor, but a design that relies on subtle variations of beige is more vulnerable.

Comment: Any local adjustments you make *may* cause a new, even less desired, appearance elsewhere.  I will say that as designers (or business operators) we **often** see things exponentially more often than any client or customer will *ever* see the same thing. What may become overused or "played out" to us, is *rarely* the same for others. I'm sure T-Mobile designers are sick of the pink. `:)` I think the *best* you could possibly do is use a "web safe" color since there's less chance of wild variations (but a limited palette as well.) But that's no guarantee. Some screens will never be calibrated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay lets wrap what im saying in one post. So you have 2 problems

1. You dont know if your monitor is correct
2. You dont know how other peoples monitors show things

First order of business is to measure your monitor. There is no way around this, if you dont meeasure then we can never do anything about point 1. All monitors colors drift over time, and all montors have a environment that affects how the color seems to be. You need to measure your situation so that we can eliminate any error caused by you monitor, monitor drift, OS, room color and room lights.

ONce your monitor is known you can do one fo 2 things:

1. set the monitor to show sRGB or
2. use the graphics software to emulate sRGB

Why would you do that? Well, all images shown on the web should be displayed as if they were in sRGB colorspace. Thats the definition of what it should show. All errors beyond this is about mismanagement, poor hardware and lack of ever having to measure the system.

This does not entirely guarantee that you can get to the average across monitors. But you would get to the  target of all monitors. Any good monitor and OS that hasnt been adjusted by the user should have started their initial drift from this position, or atleast tring to emulate this position. Any bad monitor would be whatever.

Yes this is exactly the same step thet you use to match a printer, because it is in fact the same problem.

If you want to go further measure a sample of devices that you have been suprised over, then you can add those devices to the stack of things to emulate to see values can be if you must. But really i wouldnt bother its just depressing.

PS: When i first started measuring monitors for people i was supprised about how much off the colors colors where even for really high end systems.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is calibrate your monitor. Normally using a colorimeter like Xwrite Display Pro or Datacolor Spyder.

A primitive way to do it is manually.

You need to define the parameters of your monitor like white point, brightness and contrast, and then manipulate the gamma.

Here is a very, very basic tutorial I did ages ago. https://otake.com.mx/ColorCalibration/
To see the gamma patterns you need to deactivate any zoom on your browser.

---

My neverending joke.

A drunk driver listens on the radio.

"One person is driving the wrong way on the highway"

-- One? There are many!

You simply do not want to be the drunk man.

Comment: I dont thik fixing your gamma does anything for color issues op is asking about.

Comment: I'm not asking how to make the colors on my monitor as close as possible to what they might be in real life. I am asking for how to make smart color choices that minimize differences across different types of devices in their default configurations.  

In fact adjusting my screen colors will make things worse because then the colors on my display will be different to the vast majority of other identical devices. (Which is what I am trying to avoid)

Comment: @Jay This minimizes the difference across different types of monitors (or atleast to best of our ability). Every device  should be adjusted so that it it showing web images as sRGB! Therefore adjusting your monitor so that you can verify that you see sRGB is the only thing you can do. That eliminates any error you have then what you are left with is error people have with in their devices which you have no control over. There are no good statistics on what the average error is, because that would mean that all monitors tested would show sRGB, so best you can do is make sure you have no error.

Comment: "act adjusting my screen colors will make things worse because then the colors on my display will be different to the vast majority of other identical devices". No, each device will display differently over time. So your monitor does not look identical to a identical monitor that came off the manufacturing line. Homing to sRGB eliminates any mistake that you might have made in your color settings, this is the best you can hope to accomplish (make the color that should be correct).

Comment: @Jay also you dont have to adjust your monitor, other then setting it to defaults, just measure it and make a profile so that your application knows what your monitor shows it can then emulate sRGB to the best of its ability so that you can ask it to show how much your moinitor is drifting trough the baseline. Measuring your monitor is the first and only step you can take to know what is what. Emulating paper and other monitors have the same requirements.